# I will have been staying there for good after I passed the exam.(future perfect continuous)

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, future-tense, future-perfect, future-continuous

Let's say you were asked what are your plans in the future. Then you answered, to live in the U.S.A for the rest of your life after you passed an exam. You say:

> 1)I **will have been staying** in the USA **for good**, **after I passed** the exam.

- Will have been staying-future perfect progressive(active voice)
- For good-duration
- After+past simple verb(start of the period)

  > COMPARED TO:
  >   2)We **will be staying** in the hotel **for a week tomorrow.**(passive voice)

In a non-native english speaking country, I am accustomed to say and hear just the #2, and hadn't known there's an active form of it. After some readings, I am asking, by the way I summarized and structured it, DO I NOW UNDERSTAND THE WHOLE THING?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say "after (some action in the future)", it should be

> after I **pass**

We don't want to use the [simple past](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-past-tense/), because we're not talking about something in the past.  "After I (simple past)" is about something that has already happened, but we are talking about the future here.

If you want to talk about what you will do in the future, it's just the simple future

> I **will stay**

The [future perfect continuous](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/future-perfect-continuous/) "I will have been staying" means that at some time in the future, you have *already* been staying, before you pass: it is used for looking *backwards* from the future.  You would use it like "By Christmas, I will have been living in the US for six months."

But that's not what you mean here; you want to say you will do something *after* you pass, so the simple future is appropriate.  Another possibility is

> I **will be staying**

because you are saying you will be performing some ongoing action ("staying") in the future.

So the sentence is actually much simpler than you were trying to make it:

> **I will stay in the USA for good after I pass the exam.**

---

As for sentence #2, it is perfectly well-formed and correct.  I'm not sure what you mean by "I hadn't known there's an active form of it"; #2 is an active sentence.